# Assigning type when using JSON.parse for objects with many fields

Tags: typescript

I have a json file that serves to map a name (string) to an id (number), but the data field is stringified.

```
{ data: "{\"tim\":0,\"john\":1,\"bill\":2}, ..., \"nthName\": n }"
```

After calling `JSON.parse` on the data field and assigning to nameToIdMapper, I am going to pass nameToIdMapper to multiple functions and I don't want to declare it as type any in the function declarations.

Is there a way to describe the expected structure of an object, similar how you would via tuples, something like:

```
import nameData from './name.json'

type NameToId = [string, number]
const nameToIdMapper: {nameToId} = json.Parse(nameData.data)
```

or is this just a practical use case of using type `any`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const nameToIdMapper = JSON.parse(nameData.data) as { [key: string]: number }`

Try this.

Comment: That did it! Thank you